# Inserting value in the back of linked list

Tags: c

Im currently having some trouble trying to write this function in which it could insert the value through the back of the list, for example

[3 7 8]

insert tail 2

[3 7 8 2]

here is the code:

```
bool q_insert_tail(queue_t *q, int v)
{
      
    list_ele_t *newt;
    newt=malloc(sizeof(list_ele_t));
    newt->value= v;
    newt->next=q->tail;
    q->tail=newt;
    
    if(q==NULL) return false;
    else
    return true;
    
}
```

Comment: `q->tail` is not reachable from any other element after this function is called

Comment: @jbztt: this should not be a problem if it is called `tail` by accident but is the *head* of the list...

Comment: We need a [mcve]. Here without knowing about `queue_t` and `list_ele_t` I cannot guess what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As from what I understand, you want to avoid iterating through entire list? It would need a pointer which would always point to the last element (which means it'd not be a part of the list, but a separate indicator that would be updated every function call). If the list was empty, the pointer would be NULL head.

```c
bool push_back(tnode **ptr, char var)
{   
    tnode *el = malloc(sizeof(tnode));
    if(!el)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return false;
    }
    el->value = var;
    el->next = NULL;
    
    if(*ptr == NULL)
    { //list is empty - adding first element
        *ptr = el;
        *ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        *ptr->next = el; //attach new element to the tail
        *ptr = el; //make sure the tail pointer actually
                   //points to the last element
    }
    return true;    
}
```

I am new to coding as well, so I might have done some mistakes. Be careful with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to append to the list.

It seems that you are trying to create a one-way linked list. So, I think this example is answering the question `how to append to list` and how to adapt it to tour needs you know

```
#define MAX 2  // Define default size to add to list

typedef struct {
    int max;    // MAXIMUM amount of elements in current list
    int count;  // How many items in list is actually present now
    int *lst;   // List
} list;

bool append(list *lst, int var) {
    // If there is now space for append new element
    if (lst->count == lst->max) {
        lst->lst = realloc(lst->lst, lst->max * sizeof(int) + MAX);
        lst->max += MAX;
    }
    lst->count++;
    lst->lst[lst->count - 1] =
        var;  // lst->count - 1 because list indexes started from 0
    return true;
}

int main() {
    list lst;
    lst.lst = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    // Just fill structure
    lst.max = MAX;
    lst.count = 2;
    lst.lst[0] = 1;
    lst.lst[1] = 2;

    append(&lst, 3);

    free(lst.lst);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am extrapolating based on the limited information that is given. You're probably missing this:

```
list_ele_t*v;
for(v=q->tail;v!=NULL;v=v->next){}; //ACTUALLY reach the final element of the linked list
v=newt; //set the final element to the desired value
```